# How to avoid referencing assemblies with implementation details

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, mono

I have 3 libraries, A, B and C.  A defines a persistence library contract, B implements C using MongoDb, C references A only.  I want to inject B into C without leaking anything specific to B.

Consider

```
namespace A
{
    public interface ICollectionFactory
    {
        ICollection<T> GetCollection<T>();
    }
}

using A;

namespace B
{
    public class MongoCollectionFactory : ICollectionFactory
    {
        public CollectionFactory(string host, string db, int port)
        {
            // < init readonly fields >
        }

        public ICollection<T> GetCollection<T>(){ ... }
    }
}

using A;

namespace C
{
    public class AService(ICollectionFactory collectionFactory)
    { 
        // ...      
    }
}
```

I can avoid having to reference B from C by using the various techniques within the DI libs that scan & load available assemblies and making B.dll available at runtime, easy.  BUT how can I provide the constructor arguments for MongoCollectionFactory without these details leaking into C? Furthermore C requires multiple instances of ICollectionFactory that connect to difference databases and these instances need to be bound to the correct services in C.

I have looked a Ninject and LightInject so far.  I am happy to use any mature container that works on Mono and has at least reasonable performance.

**EDIT**

I have created another assembly; the composition root 'D' which references everything else.  This and the entry point assembly are the only ones to reference the DI container. D also has the configuration for the system (connection details, endpoints etc).  I'm satisfied with this solution although I can see D becoming a monster as the system grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing here is the concept of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). In other words, what you're missing is a start-up assembly that references [all other assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application) and wires everything together.

Answer (score 1):

If your C-Service needs two different databases it needs two parameters in its constructor.

Example: if the service has to copy data from a source-ICollectionFactory to a destination-ICollectionFactory then the constructor would look like this.

```
public class AService(ICollectionFactory source, ICollectionFactory destination)
{ ... }
```

Usually you need a seperate module "D" that is responsible for wiring up all dependencies and knows the database-specific settings.